# StreamBuilder snapshot null for few seconds

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

I am trying to use the BLoC pattern with RxDart, and i would like to get an event from a list through StreamBuilder.

My problem is that when I am opening my Details Screen, for like 1sec I've got the following error message : `The method 'firstWhere' was called on null.`

Is there a way to wait getting data without adding a loading progress because I would like to keep my HeroAnimation on my image ?

```
class _EventsDetailsScreenState extends State<EventsDetailsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final eventBloc = BlocProvider.of<EventsBloc>(context);
    //Event event = eventBloc.events.firstWhere((elmt) => elmt.id == widget.id, orElse:() => null);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream : eventBloc.allEvents,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        final Event event = snapshot.data.firstWhere((elmt) => elmt.id == widget.id, orElse:() => null);
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildEventImage(context, event),
                    (event.description != null && event.description.trim().isNotEmpty) ? _buildDescriptionSection(context, event) : Container(),
                  ],
                ))
              ]),
              new Positioned(
                //Place it at the top, and not use the entire screen
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: AppBar(
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.create), onPressed: () async => print('Edit')),
                  ],
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //No more green
                  elevation: 0.0, //Shadow gone
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventImage(BuildContext context, Event event) {
    return Hero(
      tag: 'eventImg${event.id}',
      child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/croatia.jpg"),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, bottom: 250.0),
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 30.0,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Text(
                      event.name,
                      style: eventNameTextStyle,
                    )),
              ),
              Container(
                  child: Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Text(
                          "In ${event.date.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays} days",
                          style: eventDateTextStyle)))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have solved this already ,
but I faced the same problem while working with BLoC Pattern in Flutter.
The problem comes from the fact that streams are **asynchronous** and the build method is **synchronous** .

- *This is from the official docs* :

> The initial snapshot data can be controlled by specifying initialData.
> This should be used to ensure that the first frame has the expected
> value, as the builder will always be called before the stream listener
> has a chance to be processed.
> [StreamBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

So in order to avoid this behavior **you have to use initialData property** in the StreamBuilder.

To use this with a BLoC  you could expose a simple **getter** at your BLoC that get **synchronous** value of your *current **state*** to give as an initial data for any new subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if` statement to check if the snapshot has data, this way `firstWhere` function will only be called if there's data in the snapshot :

```
 class _EventsDetailsScreenState extends State<EventsDetailsScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final eventBloc = BlocProvider.of<EventsBloc>(context);
  //Event event = eventBloc.events.firstWhere((elmt) => elmt.id == widget.id, orElse:() => null);
  return StreamBuilder(
  stream : eventBloc.allEvents,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
   if(snapshot.hasData){
     return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildEventImage(context, event),
                (event.description != null && event.description.trim().isNotEmpty) ? _buildDescriptionSection(context, event) : Container(),
              ],
            ))
          ]),
          new Positioned(
            //Place it at the top, and not use the entire screen
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.create), onPressed: () async => print('Edit')),
              ],
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //No more green
              elevation: 0.0, //Shadow gone
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }else{
    return Scaffold();
  }
});
}
```

Comment: It works but it cancels my Hero Animation so I get a behavior that I don't want to have.

Comment: I wish I can help you with that.